# Difference between an array and an address of an array

Tags: c, pointers

If I compile the following code using gcc `array` and `&array` evaluate to the same address:

```
int array[10];
int main() {
    printf("0x%x, 0x%x", array, &array);
}
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Try `sizeof(array)` vs `sizeof(&array)`, and you will see the difference, for example `array + 1 != &array + 1`.

Comment: clearly ‘sizeof(array)‘ gives me 10-times the size of an integer and ‘sizeof(&array)‘ gives me the size of a pointer. But how does that answer my question?

Comment: You asked what the difference was.  It was also noted that `array + 1 != &array + 1` because `array + 1` will do `array+sizeof(int)` at a byte level whereas `&array + 1` will do `array+sizeof(int)*N` at a byte level, where N is the number of items in the array.  The types are different as well -- a fact of which you're apparently aware.